# Recursively turn expression into nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

I've been trying to write a simple function that turns an expression into a nested list. So for example, a+2b+3c becomes {a,{2,b},{3,c}}. This is what I wrote:

```
toList[x_] := Module[{}, 
                x = List@@x; 
                For[i=1, i <= Length[x]; i++, 
                  If[x[[i]] != List@@x[[i]], x[[i]] = toList[x[[i]]]]
                ];
                x
              ]
```

However, I keep getting errors like "Tag Plus in a+2b+3c is protected" and "a+2b+3c in the part assignment is not  symbol." How can I fix what's going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
Apply[List, a + 2 b + 3 c, All]
```

This simply applies `List` to all parts of the expression in one go.

Alternatively:

```
Replace[a + 2 b + 3 c, _[args___] :> {args}, All]
(* {a, {2, b}, {3, c}} *)
```

The idea here is to replace the head of any expression with `List`. Note that `Replace[…,…,All]` is not equivalent to `ReplaceAll[…,…]` (i.e. `…/.…`). The former replaces from the inside out, while the latter from the outside in (and ignores parts that have already been touched)

## Your attempt

As to why your attempt doesn't work:

- Function arguments are not variables (as in their value can't be modified). This is the reason for the "Tag … is protected" errors. To fix this, copy the value to a local variable
- `For` does not localize the iteration variable, so `i` is shared across recursive calls. To fix this, localize `i` explicitly.
- [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)/[`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) (`==`/`!=`) is for value equality, and doesn't evaluate in many cases (e.g. `a==1` is not `False`). To do structural comparisons, use [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)/[`UnsameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html) (`===`/`=!=`).

Changing only what's necessary in your code yields the following working version:

```
toList[y_] := Module[
  {x = y, i},
  x = List @@ x;
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[x], i++,
   If[x[[i]] =!= List @@ x[[i]],
    x[[i]] = toList[x[[i]]]
    ]
   ];
  x
  ]

toList[a + 2 b + 3 c]
(* {a, 2 b, 3 c} *)
```

Further simplifications could be:

- Replace the `For` loop with `Do` (which *does* localize the variable)

  ```
  toList[y_] := Module[
    {x = y},
    x = List @@ x;
    Do[
    If[x[[i]] =!= List @@ x[[i]],
      x[[i]] = toList[x[[i]]]
      ],
    {i, Length@x}
    ];
    x
    ]
  ```
- Replace the `For`/`Do` loop with `Map` (the `If` now needs to return something in both cases, as the output is used):

  ```
  toList[y_] := Module[
    {x = y},
    x = List @@ x;
    x = Map[
      If[# =!= List @@ #,
        toList[#],
        #
        ] &,
      x
      ];
    x
    ]
  ```
- Remove the unnecessary local variable `x`:

  ```
  toList[y_] := Map[
    If[# =!= List @@ #,
      toList[#],
      #
      ] &,
    List @@ y
    ]
  ```
- Move the termination condition for the recursion into the function definition itself using [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`):

  ```
  toList[y_] /; y =!= List @@ y := Map[
    toList[#] &,
    List @@ y
    ]
  toList[y_] := y
  ```
- Use shorthands for `Map` (`/@`):

  ```
  toList[y_] /; y =!= List @@ y := toList /@ List @@ y
  toList[y_] := y
  ```
- Remove the termination condition completely (it's not needed, as `Map`/`Apply` don't do anything on expressions that have "zero length" (i.e. atoms)

  ```
  toList[y_] := toList /@ List @@ y
  ```

Comment: Yes, it is a matter of replacement of heads.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That is a really detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = a + 2 b + 3 (4 E^x + 3 x);

ReplaceRepeated[expr, f_[args___] /; (TrueQ[f =!= List]) :> List[args]]

(* {a, {2, b}, {3, {{4, {E, x}}, {3, x}}}} *)
```